# Trying to write a Cypress UI test that uses a passed string

Tags: javascript, cypress, ui-automation

I'm attempting to write a Cypress test that uses a string passed through by a different function.
The other function simply calls the cypress function and passes a string.
This seems to be possible from what I've seen in documentation but I can't figure out what I'm missing.
The Cypress test is just supposed to find a button based on it's title, defined by the passed string and click said button.

```
  When('I click the button ""', function (string) {
    // Clicks a button that test defines by title
    cy.get('button[title=${string}]').click
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you are using single quote instead of backtick for string interpolation. If it's not a typo you need to correct that

```
When('I click the button ""', function (string) {
  // Clicks a button that test defines by title
  cy.get(`button[title=${string}]`).click
});
```

Comment: THAT FIXED IT! I can't believe I overlooked that! Thank you so much. That's been frustrating me for a day and a half if you can believe it.